# deserializing error with date - JSON decoding error

Tags: java

I am getting a response from an api and it is failing to deserialize a date which looks like this "2021-09-10T21:48:35.352+0000". I have set up attribute in my class like below

```
 @JsonProperty("processedAt")
  private LocalDateTime processedAt;
```

org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2021-09-10T21:48:35.352+0000": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2021-09-10T21:48:35.352+0000' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23;

what format of date should I be using in class to get the date out and not fail on deserializing. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

By default `Jackson` does not support this date time format pattern. Therefore you need to explicitly mention that using `@JsonFormat` annotation. Like this,

```
@JsonProperty("processedAt")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private LocalDateTime processedAt;
```

Looking at your datetime format, you should probably use `OffsetDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`. Otherwise your timezone will be ignored (If you local timezone is `+0000`, then `LocalDateTime` should be fine).

```
@JsonProperty("processedAt")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private OffsetDateTime processedAt;
```

#### Update

If you use `OffsetDateTime`, then you don't need to explicitly mention the pattern using `@JsonFormat` annotation. Something like this sufficient.

```
@JsonProperty("processedAt")
private OffsetDateTime processedAt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not check but you are using `LocalDateTime` and are trying to deserialize a `ZonedDateTime`. Maybe change the type?

That is also in agreement with the error message that states that the error is at position 23. Exactly where the unexpected zone information starts.